# generating sequence number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Based on following TableA

```
Data
--------
Dummy1
Dummy2
Dummy3
.
.
DummyN
```

is there a way to generate sequence number while selecting rows from the table.

something like `select sequence() as ID,* from Data` that will give

```
ID  Data    
---------
1  Dummy1
2  Dummy2
3  Dummy3
....
N  DummyN
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to have a column in your table that is a sequence? Use `INT IDENTITY`.

Do you want to add a sequential number to a SELECT statement or a view?? Use the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY .....)` method.

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Data) AS 'ID',
  Data
FROM 
  dbo.YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed column:

```
CREATE Table MyTAble
(
   ID int identity(1,1), 
   Data varchar(20) AS 'Dummy' + ID
)
```